# SurfaceView without camera : preview after start rotated on 90 degree

Tags: java, android, camera

my problem.
I create app which do preview from camera on android. 
For preview while im not press on button - i used Camera , camera.open. When app started - the orientation of screen is normal.. But when i try to record video - i closed camera preview and used only  SurfaceView with  recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
It's showing me preview from camera without class Camera.
All this i do becouse it's fixed for me bug with greenish screen after recorded. 
So... this preview(which without camera) he after start always rotated on 90 degree ( Like in mode LANDSCAPE)
im try to use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE );
```

and

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT );
```

but it not fixed my problem.
So, can any one tell me how to rotate my preview(without camera) in mode like SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ??

pls tell me how to fix this problem.. i can't fix it 2-3 days :(

Regards, Peter
p.s. sorry for my bad english, hope u understand me.

it's code which i used for preview when i recorded video/audio

```
 preview = new SurfaceView(withPreview.this);
 preview.getHolder();
 holder.addCallback(this);
 holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS );
```

get picture from camera

```
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
```

now the screen rotated on 90 degree. if i set

```
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
```

than image rotated on 180 degree О_О

and set preview

```
recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
```

that's all what i need for camera preview
How u can see im not using Camera.. so i can't  us camera.parameters.setOrientation(90) //example
:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it right, that you will fix the Screen Orientation to Landscape or Portrait? Or should it be dynamic?
So if i understand you, to fix the orientation of the screen, then i prefer to add this into your Android Manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

This must inside the activity-block.

Hope this will help, otherwise tell me when it should dynmaic or so on.

Comment: this is not help for my preview.  Preview working without Camera class.. He using only from mediaRecord. but anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: To be honest your question did not make sense. How is your preview started without camera class ?

Comment: i edited my code.. there i show how im using it .forgot about main.addView(preview,dW,dH); where main it's FrameLayout.  I see picture from camera only when start to record.. so this code will good. Just have some bugs with rotation :(